# Threading: Complete N tasks in period T

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, subprocess, threadpool

**Objective**: I have *n* tasks to complete in a period *t* (say 180 seconds) where each task takes ~ 2 seconds to complete. The tasks must be uniformly distributed across the period *t*.

**Setup**: I am using a Mininet environment which uses [lightweight virtualization](http://mininet.org/overview/) to run Linux hosts. In my setup, I have 10 hosts. Each task is associated with a host (randomly chosen).

What I have done till now is, I have distributed the tasks among the 10 hosts (according to their association) and scheduled them in the background with a `random_sleep` (less than *t*) without waiting for them to complete.

```
$ sleep random_duration && do_task &
```

However, when *n* is large (> 2000) this leads to exceeding the maximum number of user processes.

*Alternatively*, I thought of creating a thread for each host and scheduling tasks in the foreground one by one (begin the next one after the previous one finishes). However, in this approach, I cannot guarantee that *n* tasks can be completed in *t*.

What would be a scalable approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: I'm not clear on the second problem: if a straightforward, full-use scheduling doesn't guarantee task completion -- this seems to imply that such a case has no acceptable solution: you have too many tasks for the time allotted.  I don't see where you're losing cycles.

Comment: Exactly. If full-use scheduling does not satisfy the total number of tasks, then it implies that I have to schedule some tasks simultaneously i.e. fork a new thread or process. However, from the first case, we see that forking a new process for every task is too much . So I need a kind of hybrid approach...

Comment: Oh ... so the tasks do *not* consume 100% of a critical system resource?  2 tasks can complete in less than the sum of their individual times?

Comment: Also, are the tasks homogeneous -- all takes take the same amount of time?  Are they independent, or must they be run in a given order?

Comment: Yes. If both of them start at the same time, they can finish in ~2ms total. No, they do not, individually, consume 100% of a critical system resource. However, scheduling 2000 of them at the same time does make the system crash. Simultaneously it works up to ~200 of them. The tasks are order-independent, and each task takes around the same time (on the order of  a few ms)

Comment: Ah ... your question cites 2 sec, not 2 ms.  Thanks.

Comment: The 2ms in the comment was by mistake. It is indeed around 2 second for each task. However, the variation between times taken for each task is in ms i.e 2 sec +- x ms for each task

Comment: Can you efficiently detect the quantity of active processes, or know when a process finishes (other than simply waiting for the one-and-only process to finish)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you can somehow track the quantity of running tasks, then I see a solution.  Access or hard-code the MAX_PROCESSES limit.  Have all of your processes into a queue (or any collection).  If `n < MAX_PROCESSES` (with a few left over for normal system work), then you already know how to handle the work.

Where `n` is too large, then still compute the scheduling interval `time_allowed * processor_count / n`, but schedule only the first `MAX_PROCESSES * ratio` tasks, for some `ratio` < 1.0.  Apportion them equally among the processors.  As processes complete (perhaps when half of the scheduled ones finish), then schedule another batch of tasks, always keeping the quantity of active tasks somewhat more than `processor_count` (10, in your example), but comfortably less than `MAX_PROCESSES`.

Does that handle your problem?